# How to Move All tables from one Database into Different Database?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008-r2, oracle-sql-developer

I am using Oracle SQL Developer and I have ten tables. Now I want to move all 10 tables from Oracle into a SQL Server 2008 R2 database. Is there any easy solution for this task?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to do this one that go beyond what I listed, but here's a start.

1) You could try the SQL Server Migration Assistant for Oracle.  It's free and usually works well for me for smaller or medium sized datasets.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28766

2) Create a SSIS package.

3) You could create a linked server in SQL and then select * from Oracle into SQL table (messy and probably not a good idea).

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/280106

4) Export to flat files and import into SQL.  Again, a ton of caveats with this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Data Pump for SQL Server](http://www.sqlmanager.net/products/mssql/datapump) which allows transfering tables from any ADO-compatible data source including Oracle to MS SQL Database. It is not free but can be setup quickly.